# Is the sentence "How was the forest born" grammatically and logically correct in English?

Tags: titles

Is the sentence "How was the forest born" grammatically and logically correct in English? I want it to be a title for a video, showing how trees are being planted and growing.

Comment: Is it a question or a statement? "How was the forest born?" or "How the forest was born".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating a title, consider

1. "How forests are born" (If the title is about forests in general)
2. "How the forest was born" (If speaking of a certain forest in particular)

Since you're using it as the main title for a video, it has to stand on its own, unlike a subtitle that can borrow meaning from context if required.

I suggest either option 1, or if you're talking about a specific forest, Option 2, but with the name of the forest mentioned.